# How to fix apport-retrace

Tags: python, python3, segmentation-fault, apport

I am attempting to help report a bug to an ubuntu package called gnome-recipes https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/recipes/-/issues/121.

I am in the process of understanding how to create debug symbols following the ubuntu specific instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash.

```
$ apport-retrace --stdout /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-recipes.1000.crash
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.4) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
ERROR: report file does not contain one of the required fields: Package
```

for completeness:
5.4.0-72-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:35:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Does this mean that I am missing something on the gnome-recipes package or does this mean that I messed up my python install or does it mean both things?